# Django: Apache Virtual Host giving 500 server error

Tags: django, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I don't know why I'm getting this error:

```
500 - Internal Server Error
```

In my httpd.conf I put the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/django/projects/blunne/blunne/wsgi.py"
    ServerName teste.blunne.com
    Alias /static "/var/django/projects/blunne/static/"
    <Directory "/var/django/projects/blunne/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What's wrong with this code?

blunne is the name of my application, it works fine on development server.

I tried to change the paths, put the code without quotation, make a custom wsgi in the path: "/var/django/projects/blunne.wsgi" with the following code

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.sep.join(os.path.abspath('/var/django/projects/blunne/').split(os.sep)))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blunne.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But always the same error... If i delete the virtualhost Apache gets normal

.

**EDIT:** In my localhost with wamp (Windows 7), I can run django with the following:

.

FILE: httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# httpd.conf includes conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Django/projects/blunne.wsgi"

ServerName beta.blunne.com
Alias /static "C:/Django/projects/blunne/static/"

<Directory "C:/Django/projects/blunne/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

FILE: C:/Django/projects/blunne.wsgi

```
import os, sys
#sys.path.append(os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2]))
sys.path.append(os.sep.join(os.path.abspath('C:/Django/projects/blunne/').split(os.sep)))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blunne.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Then I configured hosts to

```
127.0.0.1 beta.blunne.com
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you checked the apache logs http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html. Also might be worth setting DEBUG to true in settings.py just to confirm it is apache.

Comment: Django is already with Debug=True :/